# How to add the next date of subscription if the month is January from 29,30,31 to avoid the same date in February in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, calendar, set

I would like to set the `month` and `date` of next month from the date of subscription.

**Example:** If today is `30th January`, then the next date of subscription should change to the `30 days after 30th Jan` means if the month is not leap then it should set to `2nd March` instead of `30th Feb`.

Along with this also when the month is `December`, the month should set to Jan.

This is the code I have thought to use which is solving my `Dec to Jan` problem but I am still unsure about the `February` thing.

```
var now = new Date();
if (now.getMonth() == 11) {
    var current = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, 0, now.getDate());
} else {
    var current = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate());
}
```

Comment: What you describe doesn't happen. You can either add add 1 month or add a fixed 30 days, the results are similar. 31 Jan + 1 month gives either 2 or 3 Mar depending whether it's a leap year or not. 31 Jan + 30 days gives 1 or 2 Mar (depending on leap year).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding 30 days to the current date will automatically get the next actual date after 30 days

the Date object will calculate the next date regardless of the number of days in the month

```js
let someDate = new Date();
let numberOfDays = 30;

someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDays); 
let dateFormated = someDate.toISOString().substr(0,10);
console.log(dateFormated);

someDate = new Date('2020-09-10');
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDays); 
dateFormated = someDate.toISOString().substr(0,10);
console.log(dateFormated);
```

Comment: But this is when the previous month will have 30 days. What about if it has 31 days and so on?

Comment: I added a new example

Comment: so adding the date automatically sets the month too? Means I don't need to setMonth externally after doing this? @Ahmed

Comment: yes you only need to add days

Comment: ok. And also if the month is Dec, it will still set the month and date respectively with January?

Comment: yep and also change the year to the next year

Comment: can you add the last example as set the date :
1) 30th Jan 2021
2) 31st Dec 2020

and then let me know the output please!!!